# Close a container on button click

Tags: java, swing, window, jbutton

I have tried to display a window from a class called testView from another class ABC. Window contains a button. I want to close the window on that button click. How can i close it?

```
public class testView extends JFrame {

  protected JButton closeButton = new JButton("Close");

  testView(){

    this.setSize(1000,700);
    this.setTitle("Test");
    Container window = getContentPane();
    window.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    this.setResizable(false);

    window.add(closeButton);
  }
}

public class ABC{
  public static void main(String[] args) {

     testView View = new testView(); 

     View.setVisible(true); 
  }
}
```

Window is displayed from another class ABC.How can i close the window on button click?

Comment: Just use Dispose() method to close it

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
       frameToClose.dispose();
    }
});
```

This code is adding a button action listener, then it tells the frame to close when that button has an action that is acted upon it. Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

To make window invisible you have to call

```
java.awt.Window.setVisible(false)
```

But with `dispose` method you remove your window from memory.